# Laravel 4: Dynamic db selection using Capsule

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Just trying to understand how [Capsule](https://github.com/illuminate/database) works in laravel. Everything works correctly where it is defined, however, as soon as a new page is opened it again take backs the old connection information instead of the new connection which is defined.

I believed **setAsGlobal()** basically makes it available for that particular session atleast, however, I guess I am conceptually wrong here.

It would be really nice if someone can guide through the right way to make the new database connection available globally VIA CAPSULE, there are various other ways, however this seems more promising.

It would be really nice if someone could explain the following commands in more simpler way (the comments are written as per in the documentation, however, something above that would be really nice):

```
// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));


// Set the cache manager instance used by connections... (optional)
$capsule->setCacheManager(...);


// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();



// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
 $capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837068/1216285 to use Capsule out of Laravel scope in your app. Since all the laravel components are decoupled and served as independent components in laravel project, you can use them in your app easily.