# Can we Integrate Laravel project as a library in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel, laravel-5

I want to increase the functionality of my CodeIgniter project by integrating some code that is written in laravel? how do I approach,
Can I include the code via library in CodeIgniter ? If yes How?
*I only want to include controllers and ORM into the CI.*

> Laravel code is a kind of api fetcher with function talks with other
>   3rd party services.

Comment: It totally depends on the code you have. If it is using a lot of Laravel-specific classes and helpers, you would need to write a lot of wrappers for them in CI or rewrite your Laravel library to use CI-classes and helpers instead. It's usually easier to just rewrite it completely in CI.

Comment: You want to add the whole app? Or maybe you can just get few functionality like Eloquent ORM and controllers that use it to get data from database? Please be more specific what the laravel code does. Cause if you just use it to send API requests to 3rd party services you can just include Guzzle or something similar.

Comment: Wrapping is possible via library only ? any other approach possible ?@MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can use composer to install Laravel specific modules/projects, third-party projects in your CodeIginter. Just include `autoload` in your `index.php' file at top

```
// Composer autoload
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

I am using `Eloquent` as ORM in my CodeIgniter codebase.

Create a classmap to your app directory in `composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "YourApp\\": ["application/"] },
```

### Use Eloquent

To use `Eloquent`, you will require to create a library to setup Eloquent for use.

```
/**
 * Capsule setting manager for Illuminate/database
 */
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as CapsuleManager;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class Capsule extends CapsuleManager {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

    //Loaded by CI
    if(function_exists('get_instance')) {
      $ci = &get_instance();
      $db = new stdClass;
      $db = $ci->db;
    } else {
      require_once __DIR__.'/../config/database.php';
      $db = (object) $db['default'];
    }

    $this->addConnection(array(
      'driver'    => $db->dbdriver,
      'host'      => $db->hostname,
      'database'  => $db->database,
      'username'  => $db->username,
      'password'  => $db->password,
      'charset'   => $db->char_set,
      'collation' => $db->dbcollat,
      'prefix'    => $db->dbprefix,
    ));

    $this->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

    // Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
    $this->setAsGlobal();

    // Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
    $this->bootEloquent();
  }
}
// END Capsule Class
```

Now load the auto load the library, and you have the eloquent beauty.

Similarly, you can use `MonoLog` for logging, `Whoops` for error display, `Formers\Former` for form building etc.

### Use Whoops

You can place this code somewhere after `autload` and defining CI Environment in your `index.php` to use beautiful https://github.com/filp/whoops library

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
    $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
    $whoops->pushHandler(new Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());
    $whoops->register();
}
```

You can also extend `CI_Router` to use Laravel style routing in your Code Igniter app.

### Blade Templating

You can extend the `CI_Loader` to use `Blade` templating in Code Igniter. Create a new file `MY_Loader` in your `application/core` directory with this code.

```
use Illuminate\Blade\Environment;
use Illuminate\Blade\Loader;
use Illuminate\Blade\View;
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function blade($view, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->config->load('blade', true);
        return new View(
            new Environment(Loader::make(
                $CI->config->item('views_path', 'blade'),
                $CI->config->item('cache_path', 'blade')
            )),
            $view, $parameters
        );
    }
}
```

You may have to create a config file `blade.php` in your `application/config` directory to store `blade` specific configurations.

```
//config/blade.php
$config['views_path'] = APPPATH . 'views/blade/';
$config['cache_path'] = APPPATH . 'cache/blade/';
```

Now you can do something like this in your controller

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        // Prepare some test data for our views
        $array = explode('-', date('d-m-Y'));
        list($d, $m, $y) = $array;
        // Basic view with no data
        echo $this->load->blade('home.index');
        // Passing a single value
        echo $this->load->blade('home.index')->with('day', $d);
        // Multiple values with method chaining
        echo $this->load->blade('home.index')
             ->with('day', $d)
             ->with('month', $m)
             ->with('year', $y);
        // Passing an array
        echo $this->load->blade('home.index', array(
            'day' => $d,
            'month' => $m,
            'year' => $y
        ));
    }
}
```