# Integrating Laravel into Codeigniter

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, session, integration

I have an app which is written in `Codeigniter` . I need some modules for my application now . I have searched premium sites and have found some good items in them . but they are written in `Laravel` . my main problem is to integrate `Laravel` session into `Codeigniter` and I don't have enough time to implement those modules in `codeigniter`.

Is there any way I can integrate these two to work side by side ?

Comment: They're both MVC frameworks so I doubt they work well together.

Comment: @apokryfos so in your opinion it will break huh ?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34836659/can-we-integrate-laravel-project-as-a-library-in-codeigniter

Comment: its critical for me now .

Comment: Its mainly about sessions . I dont want my Authentication system to break

Comment: Laravel is modular and there are some modules that can run without the main MVC framework to be included, however if you require the main MVC framework to run then you'll have issues on e.g. how's managing the routing and authentication etc.

Comment: Yes they are big issues

Comment: I think the most realistic approach is to build an API project based exclusively on Laravel that you can call via your CI project using something like Guzzle or cURL for a sort of "bridge" of the two frameworks.

Comment: @apokryfos yes I think its a good solution

Comment: I agree with, @apokryfos. reasonable solution